# JUnit 5 console launcher does not find tests inside JAR

Tags: junit5

I have a shaded uber JAR containing test classes and all dependencies.  But the JUnit 5 console launcher fails to find any tests:

```
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone.jar --scan-classpath=/path/to/test-suite-all.jar
╷
├─ JUnit Jupiter ✔
└─ JUnit Vintage ✔

Test run finished after 33 ms
[         2 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         2 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         2 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         0 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         0 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         0 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]
```

Test class names end in `Test`, matching the default `--include-classname` regex.

Should I expect this to work?  What am I doing wrong?

These attempts also fail in the same way:

```
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone.jar --scan-classpath -cp=/path/to/test-suite-all.jar
java -cp junit-platform-console-standalone.jar:/path/to/test-suite-all.jar org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher --scan-classpath
```

**Update**

[Minimal example repository](https://github.com/hertzsprung/junit-console-launcher-shaded-jar), run with `./gradlew junitConsoleLauncher`.  This repo now works correctly thanks to [johanneslink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32352/johanneslink)'s suggestions.

Comment: —scan-classpath takes the actual class path not a jar file. Afaik.  So you have to add your uber jar to the classpath using -cp option.

Comment: @johanneslink I tried a couple more variations (see updated question) and get the same problem

Comment: Can you provide a repo with full reproducible example?

Comment: Example repository at https://github.com/hertzsprung/junit-console-launcher-shaded-jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After cloning your repo and adding a repo to the build file, the following worked for me:

```sh
gradle wrapper
./gradlew shadowJar
java -cp ./build/libs/junit-console-launcher-shaded-jar-all.jar org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher --scan-classpath ./build/libs/junit-console-launcher-shaded-jar-all.jar
```

Output:

```
╷
└─ JUnit Jupiter ✔
   └─ ExampleTest ✔
      └─ test() ✔

Test run finished after 50 ms
[         2 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         2 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         2 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         1 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         1 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         1 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]
```

Using `-jar` option does not work, probably because the manifest is not correctly set in the shadow jar.

Comment: Can you confirm your `java` command?  This doesn't work for me because `junit-console-launcher-shaded-jar-all.jar` doesn't include the console launcher.  With the console launcher JAR downloaded in the current working directory, `java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.8.2.jar --scan-classpath ./build/libs/junit-console-launcher-shaded-jar-all.jar` runs but I still can't persuade it to find any tests.  I must be doing something silly.

Comment: Ah, never mind, your answer _does_ work with some minor modifications to my repository, so that the uber JAR includes the console launcher.  When running the `junitConsoleLauncher` Gradle task, you [must explicitly specify the Java toolchain launcher](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/16791#issue-855982209).